# How to display scraped codes in Terminal

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, terminal

I scraping some data but I want to check it on terminal screen. I create command in Laravel. When I use the command want to display scraped data in Terminal. Do i need to use json encode and var_dump it. But I already tried it. Here is my codes...

```
$start_id = 4710000;

$url = 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K'.$start_id;
$html = file_get_contents($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMParser->loadHTML($html);

$getAllTable = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('table');
json_encode($getAllTable);
echo $getAllTable;
```

Any idea? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Nothing special needed. You could use `$this->info()`, `$this->error()` or `$this->line()` to output different message types. If you want to output json you should change `json_encode($getAllTable);` to `$getAllTable =json_encode($getAllTable);`

Comment: I've tried it but the out put is like `show data : {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one for laravel command line

```
$this->info('show data :- '.print_r($getAllTable,true));
```